# How to add shapes/patterns on top of a specific object?

Tags: modeling

I've recently started up with Blender. I'm working on a game about One Piece. In the series One Piece there are these devil fruits that come in many shapes. They have basically like a pattern overlay over the fruit itself and therefore arent one-shaped but rather deformed.

I've already tried to add the modifier shrinkwrap previously to a fruit i made yesterday, but that finally destroyed my computer after a ton on objects. It was also buggy, and came in random sizes.

I finally ended up with using a image texture, but that isn't what i aim for.

I would greatly appreciate any help or guidance.

(The first picture is a picture of a fruit from the series, the second one is my trial of recreation)

[image: This is a devil fruit from the series.]

[image: My work for the moment.]

Comment: are you allowed to use a height map? In that case you can create a b&w pattern, blur it a bit, paint it on a white background, and use the result as a height map?

Comment: @moonboots thats probably one of the best ideas, going to try it out.

Comment: you could also sculpt on a high-poly and bake the normals?

Comment: @moonboots I haven't really used height map yet. The object becomes fully shattered, Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: yes normal map is probably a better idea as height map may give artefacts

Answer (score 2):

You could duplicate your object, subdivide the copy with a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, sculpt the copy, maybe add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier in order to smooth the result, then bake the normals so that you can use it in a *Normal Map* node:

[image]

Comment: I'm on my way, had some troubles through the way but seems good now. If i could ask, which tool in the sculpt mode did you make the pattern with?

Comment: I've used the default brush (Draw), just press Ctrl to invert its effect

Comment: oh i found it out, i noticed that you need very many vertices to make it work good

Comment: yes, subdivide enough, or enable Dyntopo and lower down the Detail value enough

Comment: subdivide doesnt allow me to sculpt, is it a setting i must turn off?

Comment: I meant give it a Subdivision Surface modifier and apply it to increase the topology